# MAGMI Product Positioning Import

Tags: product, admin, category, import

I'm using MAGMI to import products to my Magento store.
There's an option for product positioning inside categories.
But I'm not using it right or it's not working.

On this page: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

It is saying this:

```
 Item positioning

From magmi 0.7.18 , category_ids column has been enhanced with item positioning. This feature is also supported in category importer from version 0.2+ (since category importer plugin is roughly a category_ids generator)


Sample 

store,sku,....,categories
admin,00001,.....,cat name with \/ in the name and positioning::3 <= here we "escaped" the tree separator with a backslash , the category will be created as "catname with / in the name and positioning"
                                                                     sku 00001 will be set with position 3 in the category
```

So how exactly should I use product positioning?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this to work I changed some MAGMI core files.
And right now I use Category::position for positioning.

And for Custom Options

Initially it was something like:

```
To provide additional options for new categories, the following syntax can be used:

category name::[is_active]::[is_anchor]::[include_in_menu]

where:

is_active: 0 or 1 - category is_active flag (defaults to 1 if not set)
is_anchor: 0 or 1 - category is_anchor flag (defaults to 1 if not set)
include_in_menu: 0 or 1 - category include_in_menu flag (defaults to 1 if not set)
```

Now it's:

```
category name:[is_active]:[is_anchor]:[include_in_menu]
```

So first there were some conflicts. Now there aren't anymore.

In magmi/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/categories/categoryimport.php I replaced:

1)

```
$catpos[]=(count($a)>1?$a[1]::"0");
```

with:

```
$catpos[]=(count($a)>1?$a[1]:"0");
```

(at line 220)

2)

```
$parts=explode("::",$cdef);
```

with:

```
$parts=explode(":",$cdef);
```

(line 182)

3)

```
        $attrs=array("name"=>$cname,"is_active"=>($cp>1)?$parts[1]::1,
        "is_anchor"=>($cp>2)?$parts[2]::1,
        "include_in_menu"=>$cp>3?$parts[3]::1,
```

with

```
        $attrs=array("name"=>$cname,"is_active"=>($cp>1)?$parts[1]:1,
        "is_anchor"=>($cp>2)?$parts[2]:1,
        "include_in_menu"=>$cp>3?$parts[3]:1,
```

(lines 186-188)